# Method to align and fill in lists of numbers of different lengths and resolutions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, position

I have many n by 2 matrixes, like so :

| Distance | Value | Distance.1 | Value.1 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -15 | 1 | -15 | 2 | ... |
| -14.9 | 3 | -14.995 | 4 | ... |
| -14.8 | 4 | -14.992 | 2 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 15 | 3 | 8.959 | 2 | ... |
|  |  | ... | ... | ... |
|  |  | 15.048 | 3 | ... |

The Distance columns all start at -15, and all finish around +15+-0.05.

My goal is to compute the mean value (of the value columns) and then plot those values as a function of the distance. What I am stuck on is how to 'align' all of the distances, like so :

| Distance | Value | Distance.1 | Value.1 | Mean of Values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -15 | 1 | -15 | 2 | *mean value at this distance* |
| NaN | NaN | -14.995 | 4 | *mean value at this distance* |
| NaN | NaN | ... | ... | *mean value at this distance* |
| -14.8 | 4 | -14.8 | 2 | *mean value at this distance* |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | *mean value at this distance* |
| NaN | NaN | 14.995 | 2 | *mean value at this distance* |
| 15 | 2 | 15 | 3 | *mean value at this distance* |

At the moment I am just plotting all the values against the 1st Distance column, which means that all the data points that are in columns longer than the first matrix are lost.

Here is some code. Now I know that this could hopefully be solved in an other language than python, and even then without pandas, but I am using them in my project to clean and filter the data before hand.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df0 = pd.DataFrame({'Distance':np.linspace(-15, 14.969, 100),
                        'Value':np.random.rand(100)})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Distance.1':np.linspace(-15, 15.034, 500),
                        'Value.1':np.random.rand(500)})

df = pd.concat([df0,df1], ignore_index=False, axis=1)

df['mean'] = df.filter(regex='Value').mean(axis=1)

df.plot(x='Distance', y='mean')
plt.show()
```

So with the code above, the distances are not aligned. I see two ways of solving the problem :

- Somehow add NaNs to fill in the missing values in the shorter columns, while aligning the distances which appear in all the Distance columns.
- Somehow average out the values in the longer columns. So say for every distance in the the short column, there are 3 distances in the long column, take the average of those 3 extra values and replace the 3 entries with that average.

I think, taking into account statistics, the second method is better. Because with the first method the values that only appear in the longer columns will be overrepresented in the mean compared to the values at distances that are in all the columns.

I'm guessing that there is a very clever way to use a [Lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) in combination with pandas' [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply). But I'm really not sure on how to do it. (How to get the lambda expression to look at all the columns except the longest or vice versa ? How to add values to certain columns and not others ?)

I've come up with this so far :

for each row, compare the value in the distance column to the distance value of the longest distance column. If its the same, go to next column, else somehow insert NaN values and shift all of the values in the rows below down, except those in the longest matrix (longest two columns).

Any help is appreciated. I'm sure that I am not the first person to encounter this problem, but I am really not sure how to phrase it well enough to be able to google it.